# Geometric interpretation of generalized linear model

Tags: regression, model, geometry

For linear model $y=x\beta+e$, we can have a nice geometric interpretation of estimated model via OLS: $\hat{y}=x\hat{\beta}+\hat{e}$. $\hat{y}$ is the projection of y onto the space spanned by x and residual $\hat{e}$ is perpendicular to this space spanned by x.

Now, my question is: is there any geometric interpretation of generalized linear model (logistic regression, Poission, survival)? I am very curious about how to interpret the estimated binary logistic regression model $\hat{p} =
\textrm{logistic}(x\hat{\beta})$ geometrically, in a similar way as linear model. It even does not have an error term.

I found one talk about geometric Interpretation for Generalized Linear Models. http://statweb.stanford.edu/~lpekelis/talks/13_obs_studies.html#(7). Unfortunately, the figures are not available and it is quite hard to picture.

Any help, referencing, and suggestion will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 6):

I think that you best bet is the thesis of Dongwen Luo from Massey University, *On the geometry of generalized linear models*; it is available online [here](http://mro.massey.ac.nz/handle/10179/3899). In particular you want to focus on Chapt. 3 - *The Geometry of GLMs* (and more particular in section 3.4). He employs two different "geometrical domains"; one before and one after the canonical link transformation. Some of the basic theoretical machinery stems from Fienberg's work on [The Geometry of an r × c Contingency Table](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2239685). As advocated in Luo's thesis:

> For a sample of size $n$, $R^n$ splits into an orthogonal direct sum of the sufficiency space $S$ and the auxiliary space $A$. The MLE of the mean $\hat{\mu}$ lies in the intersection of the sufficiency affine plane $T = s + A$ and the untransformed model space $M_R$. The link transformed mean vector $g(\hat{\mu})$ lies in the transformed mean space $g(M_R)$.

Clearly both $S$ and $A$ need to be at least 2-D and $R^n = S \oplus A$. Under this theoretical framework $\hat{\mu}$ and the data vector $y$ have the same projection onto any direction in the sufficiency space.

Assuming you have differential geometry knowledge, the book of Kass and Vos [Geometrical Foundations of Asymptotic Inference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometrical-Foundations-Asymptotic-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471826685) should provide a solid foundation on this matter. This paper on [The Geometry of Asymptotic Inference](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~kass/papers/geometry.pdf) is freely available from the author's website.

Finally, to answer your question whether there is "*any geometric interpretation of generalized linear model (logistic regression, Poisson, survival)*". Yes, there is one; and depends on the link function used. The observations themselves are viewed as a vector in that link transformed space. It goes without saying you will be looking at higher-dimensional manifolds as your sample size and/or the number of columns of your design matrix is increasing.